# Customise iOS smartbanner

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ios7, smartbanner

We are planning to include smart banners for our app.

Is it possible to customise smart banner. For instance, hide the close button so that user cannot close it ever.

I tried jquery plugin (https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner) .But it shows the actual Apple rendered banner and a white space (in the length of customised banner) below it. (Note: I tweaked the code to run for iOS: 6+)

I am now working on fixing this white space issue and hiding default banner using js.

Any help with regard to achieve customisation would be appreciated!

Details:

iOS version: iOS 7.1.2

Testing device: iPhone 5s

Please let me know if any other details required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you cannot change the smart banner at all.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Smart Banner plugin has the following default options, and I suggest you to use these arguments :

```
$.smartbanner({

             ...
daysHidden: 0, // Duration to hide the banner after being closed (0 = always show banner)
//you may use this one as well        
daysReminder: 0, // Duration to hide the banner after "VIEW" is clicked *separate from when the close button is clicked* (0 = always show banner)

            ...
        })
```

This should keep your banner always displayed. [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner)